# Master Scene with render queue

Tags: scene, compositing-nodes

Good afternoon!
My task is extremely simple to understand, but I still do not understand how to implement it in a blender.

Imagine that you have a scene with a ready-made model, lights, and cameras-let's call it a **master scene**.
On the render, I should get ~10 shots of this scene with different materials.

Through compositing, I want to build a queue for the render with pre-set settings, and output everything to a MultiEXR file.
The catch is that there are two types of scenes: 1. Full copy, or 2. Full Instance that cannot be edited. 2.82 a does not allow making it local, because it says that this function has not been entered yet.

Since there will be many such projects in the future, I am trying to build a template.
In which, for example, I would put the desired model with lights and cameras through a Proxy. And already on the stages, I set up the materials I needed.

Please help me figure out how to implement this.

I am very sorry for my English.